# Ansible : defined variable or output from ansible task as a variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-facts

Hi I am trying to get a task setup which is as below.

```
- name: Create a route53 record for RDS instance.
  route53:
    state: present
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_create_route53_record.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_create_route53_record.secret_key }}"
    zone: "{{ aws_create_route53_record.zone }}"
    hosted_zone_id: "{{ aws_create_route53_record.id }}"
    type:  "{{ aws_create_route53_record.type }}"
    value: "{{ aws_create_route53_record.value }}"
    record: "{{  aws_create_route53_record.record }}"
    private_zone: "{{  aws_create_route53_record.private_zone }}"
    ttl: 30
```

Now I know passing variable from `group_vars/all.yml` I can define `aws_create_route53_record.value` in `group_vars/all.yml` and use it however in certain cases there is possibility where I am going to use this task as role and want to pass `aws_create_route53_record.value` runtime from previous task to this one and use it in creation of route53 record. for e.g. creating a rds instance using ansible task and use `rds endpoint` as value for `route53_record` 
Any suggestion would help a lot. Thanks

Note: I've checked [`rds module page`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/rds_module.html) for return values which I thought would use instantly to solve this however there is no provision for endpoint return in it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by using a variable in my task and initially assigning it the value of group_vars variable and putting a condition that if after assigning a value of group_vars variable, variable is still blank then take a value from last task. Below is the code snippet which works fine. You would need to register variable from previous task as `endpoint_host`

```
---
-
  name: "Set facts of record value"
  set_fact:
    record_value: "{{ aws_create_route53_record.value }}"
-
  name: "If record value not present, Look for endpoint-host variable"
  set_fact:
    record_value: "{{ endpoint_host }}"
  when: "aws_create_route53_record.value == \"\""
-
  name: "Create a route53 record for RDS instance."
  route53:
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_create_route53_record.access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_create_route53_record.secret_key }}"
    hosted_zone_id: "{{ aws_create_route53_record.hosted_zone_id }}"
    private_zone: "{{  aws_create_route53_record.private_zone }}"
    record: "{{  aws_create_route53_record.record }}"
    state: present
    ttl: 30
    type: "{{ aws_create_route53_record.type }}"
    value: "{{ record_value }}"
    zone: "{{ aws_create_route53_record.zone }}"
```

Hope this helps.